# Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой знак поставить на месте пропуска?

Tags: пунктуация, тире, бсп

Злится, но ничего поделать не может (?) напоминает себе, что не имеет права.

Это сложное бессоюзное предложение, или здесь знаки препинания работают по другому принципу? Я бы поставила тире, но не очень понимаю, как это объяснить.

Comment: По одному предложению трудно понять смысл сказанного. Хорошо бы добавить пояснения или контекст.  БСП? Но здесь есть и союзная связь (но, что).

Comment: Я думала, бессоюзная связь именно между частями предложения, которые разбиты знаком вопроса. Точно не уверена. Могу добавить такой контекст: "Он злится, но ничего поделать с этим не может (?) напоминает себе, что не имеет права это делать (злиться)".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы записала предложение в одном из таких **вариантов** (надо смотреть по контексту):

(1) *Злится, **но** ничего поделать не может — напоминает себе, **что** не имеет на это права.*

Это бессоюзная связь, второе сообщение распространяет первое, поэтому ставим **присоединительное** тире. Другие знаки вряд ли подойдут.

(2) *Злится, **но** ничего поделать не может; **только** напоминает себе, **что** не имеет на это права.*

Частица ***только*** здесь в качестве противительного союза с **ограничительным** значением.

**Пояснение**

Имеется  в виду **право (какое? на что?)**, то есть причина, основание, повод для каких-л. действий.  Например: *Имеет п. подать в суд. Не имеешь права обижаться!*

Поэтому лучше добавить **распространитель**:  *на это* или  *так делать.*